# Remotly get a list of running programs on xp?

Tags: windows-xp, wmi, remote-access

I have a bunch of pc's the I need to remotly restart, however I don't want to restart them if they are running certian applications (such as word, excell etc). Is it possible to get a list of running applications or programs using WMI or some other service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind!
I found out that SYDI has an option for this. Frickin awesome!
http://sydiproject.com/

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about sydi, but the other thing I'd recommend is "pslist" from the [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx)